# How can I check the maximum http connection numbers to per IP address through different network?

Tags: ios, performance, networking, concurrency

The question might sound a little bit odd.
The background is I'm working on some performance tuning tasks of our iOS Mobile App, and I noticed that some of the concurrent requests are blocked until the prior ones are finished. and the number of allowed concurrent live connections seem to vary from different network conditions, e.g. 3G/4G network, Edge, home broadband cable and etc.

I know from NSURLConnection, there is a limitation from the iOS SDK, no more than 5 live connections to one same host. But I'm wondering if there is additional/different restrictions from network carrier.

Does any one know how to check the number out?